# Resolution for Login Screen and Logged-In State appear different, any way to set them to the same?

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I've got what I think is an interesting occurrence.

I've got Windows 7 Home Premium x64 on my system, here.  (It dualboots with Linux, but that's irrelevant for this question).  The screen resolution according to the system when I am logged in says it is 1920x1080 which is recommended for this screen (it's a Dell, I guess it handles this much higher resolution).

But, the login screen seems to be a different resolution.  When I first turn on the computer, the password box, the username, and the user image are all larger than when in the lock screen (after I've logged in).

This question is two-fold, but ultimately they are so closely related I am not splitting them up:

1. Is it even possible for the login screen and the actual logged-in resolution to be different?
2. Assuming that it is possible for the resolutions to be different, is it possible to change this so the login screen resolution and the logged-in resolution are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Direct answers:

1) No
2) No

Sounds to me like your video driver is not functioning properly. Try clearing it with the  cleanup tool (i.e. AMD Cleanup Tool) and then reinstalling the latest package from the manufacturers site.

Comment: I'll do that when I'm back at home, I'm on a (albeit old) netbook right now while on the light rail here, with my mobile broadband, I'll let you know if this fixes things.